# DropDownListFor automatic postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, html.dropdownlistfor

How would I implement something like automatic postback for DropDownListFor in MVC. Currently,  after selecting a value in dropdown I have to refresh the page to see the changes applied to the page.

In View,

The dropdownlistfor is like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, Model.MyItemList, new { @id = "DropDownListForId"})
```

and the onchange event is handled as such

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#DropDownListForId').change(function () {
        var item = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { value: item },
            success: function(result) {

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to refresh the entire page instead of the affected section/s?

Comment: the dropdownlist selection will change culture/language of the page so needed to refresh the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply achieve this by submitting form on change event of `DropDownList`

Assuming `myForm` as you form id

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#DropDownListForId').change(function () {
        $('form#myForm').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This triggers validation in other areas of the page. Currently, I have got it working, so it only refreshes the page by adding     window.location.href = "@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")"; Any other ways? Thanks